# Generate binary string of n bits in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This is a program for generating Binary strings of n bit.I am getting a wrong result in which there is some duplication in this answer.I couldn't figure it out what's the problem?
Here is the code:

```
class GenString
    def initialize(n)
        @a = Array.new(n)
    end

    def binString(n)
        if n < 0
            @a.each_slice(3) { |a,b,c| puts [a,b,c]*'  '}
        else
            @a[n-1] = 0
            binString(n-1)
            @a[n-1] = 1
            binString(n-1)
        end
    end
end

gen = GenString.new(3)
gen.binString(3)
```

The output is:

[image]

I highlighted the repeated portions.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This program generate result repeated of original result,but i could'nt figure it out whats the problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please take the time to format your question better. It's hard to read when you ignore proper grammar, which distracts/discourages potential answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put: Because you're telling it to print twice.

Change your condition inside `#binString` to `if n < 1`, and it will work fine.

See this ideone: http://ideone.com/jjmTBh

I've just noticed that this prints the series backwards. You can swap `[a,b,c]` to `[c,b,a]` to compensate for this. I've changed the ideone to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much simpler way to generate binary strings:

```
(0..7).each do |n|
  puts "%03b" % n
end
```

Output:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Comment: Thanks thats appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

For a more idiomatic Ruby version, I'd recommend something like this:

```
def bin_string(n)
  (0..2**n-1).map { |i| "%0#{n}b" % i }
end
bin_string(3)
#=> ["000", "001", "010", "011", "100", "101", "110", "111"]
```

If you really want to output directly (I wouldn't), change the method's body to this:

```
(0..2**n-1).each { |i| puts "%0#{n}b" % i }
```